# Replace string with own contents within bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, text-processing

Given a big file (~1.000.000 lines) with the following format:

```
1.xml:LINK-ID-12$LANG,LINK-ID-242$LANG,____de-DE
2.xml:LINK-ID-323$LANG,LINK-ID-122$LANG,____en-GB
```

After processing the result should be

```
1.xml:LINK-ID-12#de-DE,LINK-ID-242#de-DE
2.xml:LINK-ID-#en-GB,LINK-ID-122#en-GB
```

The last element in a line always contains the language. The format of this element is free to choose, for demo purposes it is `____<LANG>`.

The placeholder to replace with the language `$LANG` is also free to choose.

Removing the last entry in the array is not the big deal, I'm really looking for a solution for replacement..

If possible I'm looking for a solution that does not require bash to iterate over the whole file, maybe something with awk/sed/grep (because of speed)

Comment: What have you tried before? Try and we'll help you :) (sed can indeed be a good tool for that)

Comment: Honestly I've no clue how to fetch a substring within the string and use it to replace it within the same line. I'm looking for any clue what may help to do this without iterating of the file manually

Comment: Are there always three underscores at the beginning of the last field? What's the general rule you're trying to translate to code?

Comment: The last field is the result of a merge operation - it is free to define.
Within this example I've choosen `____` but it is completly free to choose.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge operation"? This is beginning to look like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe instead of generating this intermediate file you've got, you can just replace `$LANG` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub(/^_+/,"#",$3); gsub(/\$LANG/,$3); print $1, $2}' file
1.xml:LINK-ID-12#de-DE,LINK-ID-242#de-DE
2.xml:LINK-ID-323#en-GB,LINK-ID-122#en-GB
```

Answer (score 0):

If a Perl solution is acceptable:

```
perl -pe 's/,____([^,]+)$// or next; my $x = $1; s/\$LANG\b/#$x/g'
```

If you can change the input so it doesn't have those four underscores in the last field, it would simplify the code a bit (just remove `____` from the first regex).

Idea:

For every input line, match the last field (a comma, followed by four underscores, followed by one or more non-comma characters, followed by the end of the line) and remove it (replace by nothing). If this replacement fails, leave the line unchanged and go to the next line.

If the replacement was successful, capture the contents of the removed field (minus the four leading underscores) in `$1` and copy the value into `$x` for the next substitution.

Then scan over the remaining line again and replace every occurrence of `$LANG` as a word (i.e. not `$LANGS` or `$LANGUAGE`) by a `#`, followed by the extracted string `$x`.